# ARP poison on divided network (every PC in it's own subnet)

Tags: subnet, arp

Let's say that we have a room with a router and 30 PC's plugged in. Every PC has it's own 'subnet'. If we check for available hosts via ettercap/wireshark (on any PC), it only discoveres two hosts: our own and the router. I couldn't find any switches in the room, but they are probably hidden somewhere.

My teacher gave me a task, to sniff his wordpress password. As you probably know, login is easy, cause it can be easily enumerated, for ex. with wpsniff. In my own network, in home I work on w-shark, cause I have one mask, one router and it's simple - every packet is visible.

In the class, my IP address is like '10.169.100.181' and the 'main host' is on '100.1'.

Is there any way to configure ettercap to work with VLSM subnets, or any other way to retrieve any packet that is in a different subnet, but on the same router? He said on the first lesson, that there is a plugin for Firefox, that may work with a thing like this.

I know, that this question is stupid and you'll say that I should go learn somewhere, but I don't know where. If there is someone who can point a way (just the way), I would be grateful :)

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. NE is a site to ask and provide answers about professionally managed networks. Your question appears to fall outside the areas that our community decided are on topic for several reasons. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details. It isn't a stupid question, this just isn't the correct place for it and I am unsure where it would fit best, perhaps [su]?

Comment: You might try Information Security SE

Comment: I´m agree with @RonTrunk, this question will be better there. But, if you have 30 Pc, every one on a different subnet, your teacher in one, and you on another, you will never be able to see your teacher´s traffic unless you connected between your teacher and the router, or, between the router and the dedicated link to INTERNET to reach wordpress.

Comment: Already posted on Security. I think we're not in different subnets, cause we have similar IP addresses. Mine is 10.169.100.181, colleague - 10.169.100.182. Didn't try to ping him, only tried with wireshark. Will see, thanks :)